# How can I use activeadmin's has_many form builder with mongoid's embeds_many relationships?

Tags: mongoid, activeadmin

I'm using activeadmin 0.6.1, mongoid 3.1.5, and activeadmin-mongoid 0.3.0. `embeds_many` relations are arguably the best thing about mongoid, reducing the need for additional queries to fetch related data.

But I can't find a good way to make them work with activeadmin's `f.has_many` form helper (and activeadmin-mongoid doesn't seem to provide a `f.embeds_many` version).

The best solution I've come up with so far is to use a `has_many` relation, and use [mongoid-alize](https://github.com/dzello/mongoid_alize) to denormalize the has_many fields into the parent object. But this is somewhat unwieldy, as it requires me to access them as `parent.children_fields` instead of `parent.children`, which interferes with any code that expects an array of child objects instead of an array of attribute hashes.